# Retrieve list object from HttpClient call to web api

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve a list object from Web api via code behind. I have the following code:

```
var update = new Update();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:xxxxx/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
               .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.GetAsync("yada yada yada");
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Where I'm getting confused is how to handle the data coming in so that it is in List<> format. I want to be able to enumerate through the List so I can manipulate the individual updates. When I hit the service with Fiddler, I get either a json or xml array depending on what I set the content-type to, so it works at that point. I just need some help figuring out some content negotiation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So translate the JSON to your `List<T>`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Where I'm a little confused is how to handle that in either the response or result object.

Comment: `await` the call to `ReadAsStringAsync()`, now you have the JSON string. Use JSON.NET (NuGet) to translate that string to an object: `var myList = JsonConvert.DeSerialize<List<MyObject>>(result);`. Does this answer your question?